# General Differential Equations Salt Tank question.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am attempting to model a relatively easy ODE differential problem, but I seem to be missing something.

The model will be distilled into a spreadsheet that uses the variables as inputs into the final equation. The problem is written as such
$y' = R_\text{in} C_1 - y/V_1 * R_\text{out}$.

Rate in and Rate out will always be equal to each other, but not necessarily the same. Therefore my volume will never change for each instance of the model.

$y$ is the amount of contaminant in the system at any given time.

$y'$ is change in contaminant in the system at any given time.

$V_1$ is the volume of the system, which will remain constant for each problem, but needs to be a variable dependant on the system being modeled.

C1 is concentration of the influent, which is static per instance, but variable each time the model is used.

I am trying to solve this. It has been a few years since my DiffEQ days and my attempts to solidify the model are proving fruitless. Every time I find an answer depicted, it always uses an actual number and cancelation in the derivation/integration steps.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: What does $C_1$ mean?

Comment: I apologize for missing that. C1 is concentration of the influent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "Rate in and Rate out will always be equal to each other, but not necessarily the same" engenders some hesitation in me, but I'll assume that means they are arbitrary constants at best and not functions of $y$ at the least (to ensure linearity).

If that assumption is true, we have:

- linear (no $y(t)$s or it derivatives multiplying one another);
- non-separable (cannot create the construction $ f(y) \mathrm{d}y = g(t) \mathrm{d}t$);
- non-homogeneous (since the influent acts as a source terms);
- first-order (highest derivative being $1$);
- ordinary (one independent variable)

differential equation.
Reposing the problem in a more general form by letting $p(t) = R_{\mbox{out}}/V_1$ and $q(t) = C_1 R_{\mbox{in}}$, the ODE is

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}+ p(t) y(t) = q(t)
$$

My preferred tool of choice for solving this kind of problem (and others) is the [integrating factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).
If a function $\mu(t)$ has the definition

$$
\mu(t) = \exp\left(\int p(t)\mathrm{d}t\right) \mbox{,}
$$

multiplying $\mu(t)$ through our ODE yields an exact differential **by construction** (see the Wikipedia page for details).
This means we can re-write the ODE as

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left[\mu(t) y(t)\right] = \mu(t)q(t)
$$

We can now solve the ODE by integrating definitely

$$
\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t'} \left[\mu(t') y(t')\right]\mathrm{d}t' = \int_{t_0}^{t}\mu(t')q(t') \mathrm{d}t'
$$

$$
\mu(t) y(t) - \mu(t_0) y(t_0) = \int_{t_0}^{t}\mu(t')q(t') \mathrm{d}t'
$$

$$
y(t) = \frac{\mu(t_0)}{\mu(t)} y(t_0) + \frac{1}{\mu(t)}\int_{t_0}^{t}\mu(t')q(t') \mathrm{d}t'
$$

Plugging in our actual, constant data into the integrating factor, then into the above formula, letting $y(t_0) = y_0$, and simplifying yields

$$
y(t) = C_1 V_1 \frac{R_\mbox{in}}{R_\mbox{out}}\left[1- \exp\left(\frac{R_{\mbox{out}} (t_0 - t)}{V_1}\right)\right] + y_0\exp\left[\frac{R_{\mbox{out}} (t_0 - t)}{V_1}\right]
$$

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I attempted to use your equation, and for some reason I am not getting something that makes sense to me. 

C1 = 6000 ppm (influent) 

Rin = 151 L/Min t = 5 

V = 38000 gal or 143939.39 L 

y0= 220227272.7 

My number coming out doesn't make sense. I would expect some movement from the initial, but not a lot. A few ppm at least. I modified all characters to the same units and for some reason everything comes out strange. The final integral takes into account C1*V1, but those two from a practical standpoint don't make sense to multiply. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct.  I initially plugged in the wrong values for the $p$ and $q$ functions, but all of the math before the final answer is correct (and the new answer is correct as well).  $C_1$ is typically taken to have units of kg/m^3 or mol/m^3, so it makes sense to multiply it by a volume to get an aggregate measure of substance.  With the units you have, you need to convert the ppm to a count per volume (in any consistent units).

Comment: That makes much more sense. I had tried with the final equation before, and then changed everything back to ppm since that is the basis for the calculations in the model. Thank you for your help!